# C# using liblas.dll (unable to load DLL)

Tags: c#, lidar, liblas

I need to read LAS file using C# for my project.

I am using the libLAS library into my project to read a LAS file and I am getting this error:

> (Unable to load DLL 'liblas1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)).

Any help?

Comment: I think you'd have to build libLAS from sources with CMake. That means you'll have to download a ton of dependencies (like parts of the boos library).. because.. even if it's a darn reader, why not fit it with the kitchen sink?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that dll file to a location where it can be found by your program.  First thing, find the file.  Next, add it as a reference in visual studio and adjust the properties so that it is copied if newer.